# ndk socket does not work on snapdragon 835

Tags: android, c++, sockets, android-ndk, adb

I'm working on an application who use NDK to connect using a socket to a DRM.

**file.cpp**

```
int conSock = accept(sockd, (struct sockaddr*)&peer_name, &addrlen);
```

> ~/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/sys/socket.h

**socket.h**

```
#ifdef __i386__
# define __socketcall extern __attribute__((__cdecl__))
#else
# define __socketcall extern
#endif

__socketcall int accept(int __fd, struct sockaddr* __addr, socklen_t* __addr_length);

#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 21
__socketcall int accept4(int __fd, struct sockaddr* __addr, socklen_t* __addr_length, int __flags) __INTRODUCED_IN(21);
#endif /* __ANDROID_API__ >= 21 */
```

<s>The application fails at this call (**accept**).</s> 
The debugger can't go further the accept call (only for the snapdragon 835)

I can't debug inside *accept* because it's a compiled library (see above)

The main problem is that it works with most of all the phones, but not with note 8, s8, Oneplus 5, which the only thing that they have in common is the processor.
I've tried also different Android versions and everything is working fine.

NB, the affected phones have Android 8.0/8.1.

I could not test with the newer Snapdragon because I don't have it at work.

Any help?

If you need more code or information please comment below.

---

EDIT

**ndk-stack :**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What is "application fails"?

Comment: That when I debug I cannot go further that point, the debugger stops, and the application loading until reaches the timeout and go back to the previous screen. @AntonMalyshev